# Lua - get indexOf string

Tags: string, lua, find, indexof

I am stuck with a problem in Lua to check whether the string value is not presented in another string.

That's how I likely will do it in Javascript:

```
'my string'.indexOf('no-cache') === -1 // true
```

but in Lua I'm trying to use `string` module which gives me unexpected response:

```
string.find('my string', 'no-cache') -- nil, that's fine but..
string.find('no-cache', 'no-cache') -- nil.. that's weird
string.find('no-cache', 'no') -- 1, 2 here it's right.. strange..
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As has already been mentioned, `-` is a pattern metacharacter, [specifically](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1):

> - a single character class followed by '-', which also matches 0 or more repetitions of characters in the class. Unlike '*', these repetition items will always match the shortest possible sequence;

You might be interested in the `plain` option for [`string.find`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.find). This will avoid the need for escaping anything else in the future.

```
string.find('no-cache', 'no-cache', 1, true)
```

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>-</kbd> is a pattern metacharacter in lua. You need to escape it. `string.find('no-cache', 'no%-cache')`